# Java потоки метод join()

Tags: java, многопоточность

главная нить вызвала вторую нить, а потом вторая - третью. после чего, в главной ните вызвался метод **join()** относительно к второй нити. продолжит ли работа главная нить, когда вторая нить завершит свою работу, или нужно также ожидать завершение третьей нити?

Comment: Если у вас есть вопрос по коду - то покажите код.

Comment: Какая ещё нить? Вроде не текстильная фабрика. Каким переводчиком пользовались?

Comment: @RomanC `нить` - один из вариантов перевода `Thread`, дабы отличать от `Stream`, который по умолчанию тоже переводится как поток.

Comment: @kami чтоб ты знал что перевод с англ. языка может быть разный, но это не относится к терминологии, используемой в печати.

Comment: расскажите, какой терминологией используется?

Answer (score 0):

`join` ждёт только тот поток, который указан. Никаких порождённых потоков он дожидаться не будет. В Яве даже нет возможности как таковой узнать, кто кого запустил.